# How can I retrieve a set of unique arrays from a list of arrays using LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I have such construction

```
List<int[]> propIDs = new List<int[]>();
```

Can I get all unique value from propIDs with LINQ.For example I have list of
    (1,2)
    (4,5)
    (1,5)
    (1,2)
    (1,5)
and I must get
    (1,2)
    (4,5)
    (1,5)

Comment: Are your `int[]`s all two elements long?

Comment: Does order matters? Is `(1,2)` same as `(2,1)`?

Comment: You could use Point() instead of int[]

Comment: If all of the elements have the same size, I'd consider `Tuple<int,int>` over `int[]`.

Comment: no (1,2) and (2,1) are different and in such case I must use int[]

Comment: @Mykhalik "no (1,2) same as (2,1) is different"... uhh what? Sorry, can you rephrase that please? :)

Comment: @Mykhalik (1,2) and (2,1) have the same length: 2. So using a `Tuple<int,int>` would work for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a complete and working application of your need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListsAndArrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int[]> propIDs = new List<int[]>();
            propIDs.Add(new[] { 1, 2 });
            propIDs.Add(new[] { 4, 5 });
            propIDs.Add(new[] { 1, 5 });
            propIDs.Add(new[] { 1, 2 });
            propIDs.Add(new[] { 1, 5 });

            var distinct = propIDs.Distinct(new DistinctIntegerArrayComparer());

            foreach (var item in distinct)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", item[0], item[1]);
            }

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private class DistinctIntegerArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
        {
            public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
            {
                if (x.Length != y.Length) { return false; }
                else if (x.Length != 2 || y.Length != 2) { return false; }

                return x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1];
            }

            public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While this will work, returning a constant (here `-1`) hash code is the _worst_ possible (still correct) implementation.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, I can understand what you're saying, and thanks for the feedback! Building a hash code that would in fact be the same when the arrays are the same is probably a better approach - especially if dealing with a ***very large set of arrays***. However, as you can see from other posts, building a hash code isn't straight forward and clearly differs by opinion. With a small set of arrays there isn't any real performance hit here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the overload of [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) that takes an equality comparer.

```
class IntPairArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] left, int[] right)
    {
        if (left.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("left");
        if (right.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("right");

        return left[0] == right[0] && left[1] == right[1];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] arr)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (arr[0].GetHashCode() * 397) ^ arr[1].GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<int[]> distinctPairs = propIDs.Distinct(new IntPairArrayComparer());
```

If you want collections larger than pairs:

```
class IntArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] left, int[] right)
    {
        if (left.Length != right.Length) return false;

        return left.SequenceEquals(right);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] arr)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = 1;

            foreach (int val in arr) hc = hc * 397 ^ val.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

If all of your `int` arrays are two elements long, you could also use `Tuple`s instead which will allow you to use the `Distinct` without a custom equality comparer:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> propIDs = [] { Tuple.Create(1,2), … };
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> distinctPairs = propIDs.Distinct();
```

Comment: what if arrays have different lengths?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't even compile. And there is a trick to getting the `GetHashCode()` method to work. You need to return a `-1` from it statically so that it will even run the `Equals` method.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: added `GetHashCode` implementation.

Comment: @daryal: the question stated the array are pairs. Obviously care should be taken when arrays are used in this way.

Comment: @daryal: added a example comparer for arbitrary length arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for any length arrays.

```
    class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(int[] item1, int[] item2)
        {
            if (item1 == null && item2 == null)
                return true;
            if ((item1 != null && item2 == null) ||
                    (item1 == null && item2 != null))
                return false;
            return item1.SequenceEqual(item2);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int[] item)
        {
            if(item == null)
            {
                return int.MinValue;
            }
            int hc = item.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; ++i)
            {
                hc = unchecked(hc * 314159 + item[i]);
            }
            return hc;
        }
    }
```

and the code for distinct:

```
var result = propIDs.Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can't use `Tuple<T1, T2>` which already provides equality you can instead create your own [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) that defines equality for arrays by simply requiring that all elements are equal sequentially:

```
class ArrayEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]> {

  public Boolean Equals(T[] x, T[] y) {
    if (x.Length != y.Length)
      return false;
    return x.Zip(y, (xx, yy) => Equals(xx, yy)).All(equal => equal);
  }

  public Int32 GetHashCode(T[] obj) {
    return obj.Aggregate(0, (hash, value) => 31*hash + value.GetHashCode());
  }

}
```

Then you can easily get the distinct values:

```
var distinctPropIDs  = propIDs.Distinct(new ArrayEqualityComparer<Int32>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public return List<Tuple<double, double>> uniquePairs(List<double[]> lst)
{
HashSet<Tuple<double, double>> hash = new HashSet<Tuple<double, double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.count; i++)
{
hash.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(lst[i][0], lst[i][1]))
}
List<Tuple<double, double>> lstt = hash.Distinct().ToList();
}

For example:
List<double[]> lst = new List<double[]> {new double[] { 1, 2 }, new double[] { 2, 3 }, new double[] { 3, 4 }, new double[] { 1, 4 }, new double[] { 3, 4 }, new double[] { 2, 1 }}; //  this list has 4 unique numbers, 5 unique pairs, the desired output would be the 5 unique pairs (count = 5)
List<Tuple<double, double>> lstt = uniquePairs(lst);
Console.WriteLine(lstt.Count().ToString());
```

the output is 5

Answer (score -1):

HashSet, a set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements:

```
var propIDs = HashSet<Tuple<int,int>>
```